# Какой веб-сервер поднять при использовании Angular+Postgress?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, postgresql

Для проекта для тестирования знаний учащихся используется вот такую связку:
PostgreSQL + Angular + Express + Nodejs. Это то, что почти знаю теоретически, а закрепить хочу на практике. 
Вопрос собственно в том, какой веб-сервер ставить в локальной сети? 
P.S. Знаю, что Angular - клиентский фреймворк.

Comment: Чем не устраивают упомянутые NodeJS + Express?

Comment: Мне говорили, что можно любой сервер. Необязательно Node.js. И этот Node.js нужен для сборки проекта Angular.
Поэтому и спросил, все верно ли я понял.

Comment: Если можно любой - любой и ставьте. Но лучше, конечно, тот, который знаете. :)

Comment: Получается, что можно ставить node.js + express как сервер и плюс PostrgeSQL. А на стороне будет крутиться Angular. :)